# Rank of a matrix with block matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, matrix-rank, block-matrices

So I'm trying to solve this -

Let $A\in M_{5\times 6}(\mathbb{R})$, $A$ has rank $4$.

Let $D=\begin{pmatrix}
I_5 & A\\ 
A^T & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$.

I need to find the rank of $D$.

My solution so far:

First, $D$ has $11$ rows and $11$ columns.

It is given that $\rho(A)=\rho(A^T)=4$.

I claim, that since $\rho(A^T)=4$, $D$ has 9 rows which are not-zeroes and LI, hence the rank of $D$ is $9$.

This seems too simple. Am I missing something? Are there any other options?

Comment: Your arguments are lacking. Sure, $A^T$ has $4$ independent rows. Bu how do you, from that, conclude that all $5$ of the *top* rows of $D$ are linearly independent from the bottom four rows of $D$?

Comment: Can you give an example where all of the top rows of $D$ are NOT linearly independent from the bottom four rows of $D$?

From all my tries, They must be LI

Comment: No, I can't give you an example because it doesn't exist. But you have to **prove** it doesn't exist. Just saying "I tried and cannot find it" is not an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited and repaired after seeing @user1551 's example.]

First, use elementary column operations to see that
$$\rho(\begin{pmatrix} I & A \\A^T & O\end{pmatrix})=
\rho(\begin{pmatrix} I & A - IA \\A^T & -A^{T}A\end{pmatrix})=
\rho(\begin{pmatrix} I & O \\A^T & -A^{T}A\end{pmatrix})
$$
and then elementary column operations to see that
$$
\rho(\begin{pmatrix} I & O \\A^T & -A^{T}A\end{pmatrix})=
\rho(\begin{pmatrix} I & O \\A^T - A^{T}I & -A^{T}A\end{pmatrix})=
\rho(\begin{pmatrix} I & O \\O & -A^{T}A\end{pmatrix}).
$$

Hence $\rho(D)=\rho(I)+\rho(A^{T}A)$.

Now treat the calculation of $\rho(A^{T}A)$ as a separate problem.

Note first that $Ax=0$ certainly implies $A^{T}Ax=0$. But the converse is true *since the field is real*: $A^{T}Ax=0$ implies $x^{T}A^{T}Ax=0$ implies $Ax=0$. Hence the null spaces of $A$ and $A^{T}A$ coincide. By the rank-nullity theorem the nullity of $A$ is $6-4=2$, so the nullity of $A^{T}A$ is 2, and so the rank of $A^{T}A$ is $6-2=4$.

Had the base field been $\mathbb{C}$ then the result would have been true on replacing $A^{T}$ by $\bar{A}^{T}$.

Comment: Why doesn't elementary columns operations affect the matrix' rank?

Comment: It is a theorem that row rank=column rank (also =determinantal rank). Essentially rank is a well-defined property of the underlying linear transformation, defined independently of the bases used to give any particular matrix representation.

Answer (score 0):

As 5xum has pointed out in a comment, you need to show that the four linearly independent rows in $A^T$ are linearly independent from the first five rows of $D$. In general, this is just not true. Here is a counterexample:
$$
\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
1&0&0&0&0 &1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0 &0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0 &0&0&1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0 &0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&1 &0&0&0&i&0&0\\
\hline
1&0&0&0&0 &0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0&0 &0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0&0 &0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&i &0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0 &0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0 &0&0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{array}\right]}_D
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|cccccc}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
1&0&0\\
i&0&0\\
\hline
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
-1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{array}\right]=0
$$
The nullity of $D$ is $3$ here. Hence the rank of $D$ is only $8$.

The field in the counterexample above is complex. This suggests that you need to use the condition that the ground field in your question is real.

Answer (score 0):

We are to find the null space of $D$. Now let a vector $(x_1,x_2,...,x_{11})$ be in null space of $D$ & $c_1,c_2,..,c_6$ & $r_1,r_2,..,r_5$ are the columns & rows of $A$. 
Now note that, taking into consideration the lower half of the $D$, $x_1r_1+x_2r_2+..+x_5r_5=0$ and then such $(x_1,x_2,..,x_5)$ is either 0 and a non null vector because $N(A^T)=(5-4)=1$.

Now for $x_1=x_2=..=x_5=0$ note that $x_6c_1+x_7c_2+..x_{11}c_6=0$ choice of this non null vector will be 2 as $N(A)=6-4=2$.

Now for non null, let, $x_1r_1+x_2r_2+..+x_5r_5=0$ then $x'=(x_1,x_2,..,x_5) \in N(A^T)$ then $x'=x_6c_1+x_7c_2+..x_{11}c_6\in C(A)$ now $x'\in N(A^T)\cap C(A)$ implies $x'=0$

Hence null space of D contains 2 non null vector so rank of D is 9